# Is it possible to install and configure a Raspberry Pi without a wired keyboard or mouse?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I've just bought the Raspberry Pi and I want to follow the NOOB tutorial in order to get the base operating system working.

I don't have any keyboard or mouse, so I have to buy them.

My idea is to buy a non-wired keyboard and mouse, but I'm not sure if this will work.

For the information I've read, first I need to buy a wired keyboard and after I can set up a non-wired keyboard. Is this correct?

Is it possible to install and configure a Raspberry Pi without a wired keyboard or mouse?

Comment: Most wireless keyboard have their own wireless protocol between the keyboard and the dongle. The dongle then acts just like a normal keyboard (HID) via the USB connection. The OS won't even see any difference between the dongle and a normal wired keyboard.

Comment: The wireless keyboard just working regardless of OS isn't universally true.  Logitech unifying receivers need to be "paired" to their devices via a windows app before they "see" each other and can be used in other operating systems (like on the Rasperry Pi).  It's what happened with my  Logitech K700 keyboard.
http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/articles/3516

Comment: Check a second hand shop if budget is an issue... Any USB keyboard should fit the bill.

Comment: @Zoot: Good to know about the logitech issue, but I'll second the assertion that *most* keyboards/mice will work.  If there's a driver disk in the box or it requires downloading of special software, that's a bad sign, however.  Go for a relatively generic one and you should be fine -- and you can always google "[brand model] linux", people who've had problems tend to report them online.

Comment: @Zoot Luckily it is no longer an issue, there is a [linux utility](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Unifying_Receiver) to pair the hardware with the receiver too. After that it is working just fine (assuming you have the appropriate module compiled within the )kernel

Comment: I've got three wireless keyboard/mouse's from Logitech and all three have been plug-n-play from the moment I put batteries in and plugged in the dongle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to install and configure a Raspberry Pi without a wired keyboard or mouse?

It should be.  I've used a wireless keyboard/mouse combo with a USB dongle; that works out of the box with the linux kernel as configured on raspbian (and almost certainly other available systems too).  Just don't get anything too wierd that requires special drivers or something (a normal standard wireless keyboard and/or mouse does not).

Note that once you've created the SD card, the configuration is pretty simple and you can run it or update the things it effects fairly easily.

> For the information I've read, first I need to buy a wired keyboard and after I can set up a non-wired keyboard. Is this correct?

I'm gonna say no, you don't need a wired keyboard first.

Comment: I have one running, never had a wired keyboard or mouse plugged in. Wireless just works.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure it without a keyboard and mouse connected to the raspberry. You will however at least need another computer then to access it through SSH. Over the SSH connection you can then install all programs you want and configure the raspberry as you like.

Comment: Are you sure SSH is enabled by default?

Comment: I thought it was, but now that you say it, that was raspbarian and I'm not sure about NOOBS. I can't check it right now, but maybe I've time to check it tonight.